# dynamically changing more than one query value in the Href attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, href

I need to change dynamically and simultaneously more than one query value in a Href attribute.
I already set correctly the part in which I select the `data-name` of some tabs that contain the query value.

But now I don't know how to set the jquery part of the code that allows me to change the url

here you can see my code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.tab-soggiorno').on('click',function(valueSoggiorno){
           console.log(valueSoggiorno['currentTarget']);
            var nameSoggiorno = $(valueSoggiorno['currentTarget']).data('name');
            console.log(nameSoggiorno);
            //var url = $("link-" + allest).attr("href");
        //$("link-" + allest).attr("href", "?pavimento=" +nome); 
      });


      $('.tab-bagno').on('click',function(valueBagno){
            console.log(valueBagno['currentTarget']);
            var nameBagno = $(valueBagno['currentTarget']).data('name'); 
            console.log(nameBagno);
            //var url = $("link-" + allest).attr("href");
        //$("link-" + allest).attr("href", "?pavimento=" +nome);   
        });

        $('.button').each(function(){
                var currenthref = $(this).attr("href");
                if(currenthref.includes('&soggiorno=')){
                    var ti=currenthref.indexOf('&soggiorno=');
                    var ti2=currenthref.indexOf('&bagno=');
                    currenthref1 = currenthref.substring(0, ti);
                    currenthref2 = currenthref1.substring(ti, 100000);
   
                }
                $(this).attr("href", currenthref1 + "&soggiorno=" + nameSoggiorno + "&bagno=" + nameBagno);
            });
            

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 16" class="tab-bagno">1</a>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 14" class="tab-bagno">2</a>
  <a data-name="Ceramica Mirage - jewels, colore 6" class="tab-bagno">3</a>
</div>
                  
                  
<div>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato 05" class="tab-soggiorno">4</a>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato Naturale" class="tab-soggiorno">5</a>
  <a data-name="Parquet Castiglioni - Verniciato 09" class="tab-soggiorno">6</a>
</div>


<a class="button" href="checkout.php?&allestimento=Silver&soggiorno=INSERT-SOGGIORNO&bagno=INSERT-BAGNO" >select</a>
```

EDIT to be more specific:

I want that, when I click on a link (please see the ), I could collect the data-name. Then, when i have that data-name I want dynamically change the query values in the `.button` href attribute. As you can see, the href has two query named &soggiorno=INSERT-SOGGIORNO and &bagno=INSERT-bagno, and for those queries I want to set rispectively the data-name as values

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow! Your question is a little vague to me, try to explain the behavior you are trying to achieve, and what did you try so far? Also the code snippet produces an error.

Comment: Hi! I want that, when I click on a link (please see the `<a>`), I could collect the `data-name`. Then, when i have that `data-name` I want dynamically change the query values in the `button` `href` attribute. As you can see, the `href` has two query named `&soggiorno=INSERT-SOGGIORNO` and  `&bagno=INSERT-bagno`, and for those queries I want to set rispectively  the `data-name` as values

Comment: Note that a `<button>` doesn't have an `href`. Use `<a>` instead

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question. In the rush of posting the question I have used the wrong tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`attr(attributeName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and return a new value.

This is also much simpler using the built in [`URL  API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) .

---

Basic example using  few data attributes and having one with different value than what is in href query string

```js
$('a').attr('href', function() {
  const url = new URL(this.href),
    params = url.searchParams,
    data = $(this).data();

  $.each(data, function(k, v) {
    if (!params.has(k)) {
      console.log('Params missing : ', k)
      params.set(k, v)
    } else if (params.get(k) !== v) {
      console.log('params have different value for : ', k);
      params.set(k, v);
    }

  });
  console.log('New query string:', url.search);
  // return new href
  return url.href;

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-foo="1" data-bar="2" href="/somepath?foo=3">Test</a>
```

Comment: Actually I need to change the href inside the `button`, not inside the `<a>`.
I need to change dynamically the `button` after clicking on an `<a>`.
I can't make it work because i have two different queries

Comment: A button doesn't have `href`. Why are you using `<button>`. The principles are the same anyway with regard to using URL API. Can pass any valid url string into it. As noted in my answer my example is basic and you would need to adapt to your situtaion. I'm not going to rewrite all your logic for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to define variables nameSoggiorno ,namaBagno  and make changes for changing href code is as below

```
     $( document ).ready(function() {
    var nameBagno ='a';
    var nameSoggiorno = 'a';
  $('.tab-soggiorno').on('click',function(valueSoggiorno){
           console.log(valueSoggiorno['currentTarget']);
            nameSoggiorno = $(valueSoggiorno['currentTarget']).data('name');
            console.log(nameSoggiorno);

           var vars = [];

           var parts = $('.botton').attr('href').replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
               if(key == 'soggiorno')
               {
                   value = nameSoggiorno;
               }
               vars.push({key:key, value:value});

           });
    var href="checkout.php?allestimento="+vars[0].value+"&soggiorno="+vars[1].value+"&bagno="+vars[2].value+"";
    $('.botton').attr('href', href)

  });


      $('.tab-bagno').on('click',function(valueBagno){
            console.log(valueBagno['currentTarget']);
            nameBagno = $(valueBagno['currentTarget']).data('name'); 
            console.log(nameBagno);
           var vars = [];

           var parts = $('.botton').attr('href').replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
               if(key == 'bagno')
               {
                   value = nameBagno;
               }
               vars.push({key:key, value:value});

           });
    var href="checkout.php?allestimento="+vars[0].value+"&soggiorno="+vars[1].value+"&bagno="+vars[2].value+"";
    $('.botton').attr('href', href)   
        });




 });
```

Comment: You need to assign href to current `botton`....not to each `<a>` or every `<a>` will have same href

Comment: What do you want to achive by adding href to button?

Comment: it should be an `<a>` not `<button>` . Made comment above about that

Comment: Actually I need to change the href inside the `button`, not inside the `<a>`.
I need to change dynamically the `button` after clicking on an `<a>`.
I can't make it work because i have two different queries

Comment: I have updated my solution as per your requirements you can check above solution :)